# iOS 5 -- presentModalViewController nils parentViewController in "self"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm still trying to figure out some iOS 5 vs iOS 4 problems in this incredibly (and unnecessarily) complicated app.

I've traced one problem down to the fact that a controller (which happens to be the navigation controller of the calling class) has a `parentViewController` attached prior to being "sent" a presentModalViewController request, but on the other side of that (in `viewWillAppear` of the "presented" controller -- haven't even returned from the call) the navigation controller (I've verified that it's the same address) suddenly has a nil `parentViewController`.

I'm reasonably certain that this behavior did not occur in iOS 4 (I've been ping-ponging back and forth between the two versions to verify behaviors).

The code is far too complicated to include here, but the call is:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:messageViewController animated:[self isAnimated]];
```

There are assertions prior to the call that the `parentViewController` of the nav ctlr is non-nil, and likewise in `viewWillAppear`.  The assertion only fails in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I hate it when people verbs nouns! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was in the manual: [Change in iOS5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController)

Comment: I noticed this problem also, but didn't find the part in the documentaion where the change was written down. Thank you for posting it. :-D

Comment: yeah, nice catch! We've been fiddling with this over here, too.

Answer (score 2):

More good information about this iOS5 change:
http://omegadelta.net/2011/11/04/oh-my-god-they-killed-parentviewcontroller/